# Building an action method that return links data and building the links using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to test how i can build `<a>` links based on the Json returned by and action method,so i have created the following action method which return static JSON-

```
public ActionResult statisjson(int start = 0, int rows = 50)
        {
string j = "{'data': [{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF?imgid=1', 'desc': 'firstdoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF?imgid=2', 'desc': 'firstdoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF?imgid=3', 'desc': 'firstdoc'}]}";
return Content(j, "application/json");

        }
```

Then i can defined the following script to build the links:-

```
$(document).ready(function getstaticjson() {




            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:1431/Home/statisjson',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (result) {

                    $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {


                        $("<a>" + val.desc + "</a>").attr("href", val.url).appendTo("#links123");

                    });
                }
            });


        });
<div id="links123"></div>
```

but no links will be build when i run the application.

Comment: Does the JavaScript console say anything?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i checked the return JSON using firebug and the JSON is recevied succsfully, but the links are not constructed.

Comment: Could you please put something along the lines of `console.log(key, val)` into the `each` loop to verify the data structure is being interpreted correctly? The jquery looks fine [from here](http://jsfiddle.net/TmfLP/)

Comment: i can not understand what do u mean?

Comment: Well, if you take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmfLP/1/), it seems the JSON is okay, and the jquery is okay, so there must be something weird going on in between the two. If you were to put `console.log(key,val)` into the `each` function you would be able to see what values are _actually_ getting passed to the jquery in your firebug console, and narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: this what i get under the firebug-->console--->ALL-->Response. {'data': [{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF?imgid=1', 'desc': 'firstdoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF?imgid=2', 'desc': 'firstdoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF?imgid=3', 'desc': 'firstdoc'}]}

Comment: ok, that's interesting, this implies we are getting a string back and not an object, or else the console would print `Object {data=[3]}`. I think the problem here is the JSON requires you to use double quotes around your identifiers rather than single quotes. Try replacing the single quotes in the string j with escaped double quotes (`\"`)

Answer (score 1):

Your code for generating links is correct and works, but you should add some things to your `$.ajax` call.

- Supply **valid** JSON using double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` for keys and string values.
- Add option `dataType: 'json'` so that your `result` variable will be an object and not string.

Working fiddle with your code available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6uJd6/)

Comment: this will raise the following error "Error 1 Too many characters in character literal" under the "var jsonText = '{"data":"   inside visual studio

Comment: You shouldn't use this piece of code: `var jsonText =` It was used for demonstration only. Just replace `'` with `"` in your JSON code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It is working. Check this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBwtw/)

```
var a = '<a ' + 'href="' + val.desc + '" >' + val.url + '</a>';
$("#links123").html(a);
```

Comment: same problme nothing will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You should return JSON like this (I have not tested code):

```
public ActionResult statisjson(int start = 0, int rows = 50)
    {
         var j = new { data = [new {url = 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF?imgid=1', desc = 'firstdoc'},...] };
         return Json(j, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
    }
```

Or you should parse result (because you are returning string from action):

```
var data = JSON.parse(result);
```

Comment: this will raise the following error "Error 1 Too many characters in character literal" under the "var j = new { data = [new " inside visual studio

Comment: You can create objects and then push them to array. That's no problem. I only showed the way to do it